# How to stop showing my under development site on Google Search

Tags: seo, google-search, static-website

Someone please help me to stop showing my under development website on Google search.

Comment: This is probably the most common way people try to keep a staging site from being indexed. With the disallow directive in robots.txt

Comment: please check this url for example:https://www.joomlasrilanka.com/web-design-development-blog/stop-google-indexing-site-construction-maintenance/

Comment: @vikrantzilpe I want do to in basic HTML site. One more thing I want to know that how much time it will take to reflect from google ??

Comment: minimum 48 hourse

Comment: hi sidharth Max yudin answer is right please try for wordpress

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Also, don't develop on the stage server. You'll face a lot of problems in the future  doing so. Develop on the local computer.

Comment: I want do to in basic HTML site. One more thing I want to know that how much time it will take to reflect from google ??